# C# Waiting for multiple threads to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows forms app that I am checking all the serial ports to see if a particular device is connected.

This is how I spin off each thread.  The below code is already spun off the main gui thread.

```
foreach (cpsComms.cpsSerial ser in availPorts)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(lookForValidDev));
    t.Start((object)ser);//start thread and pass it the port
}
```

I want the next line of code to wait until all the threads have finished.
I've tried using a `t.join` in there, but that just processes them linearly.

Comment: Strictly as a side note and not that you asked about it, but you can put IsBackground = true on the thread to not have it block the main thread if you exit the application.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (cpsComms.cpsSerial ser in availPorts)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(lookForValidDev));
    t.Start((object)ser);//start thread and pass it the port
    threads.Add(t);
}
foreach(var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

**Edit**

I was looking back at this, and I like the following better

```
availPorts.Select(ser =>
      {
          Thread thread = new Thread(lookForValidDev);
          thread.Start(ser);
          return thread;
      }).ToList().ForEach(t => t.Join());
```

Comment: This is good and simple solution. But in my case System.Threading.Thread.Join() is visible in instrumentation profiling report with high exclusive time value. Despite of this, that is a really great way.

Answer (score 16):

Use the AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent Classes:

```
private ManualResetEvent manual = new ManualResetEvent(false);
void Main(string[] args)
{
    AutoResetEvent[] autos = new AutoResetEvent[availPorts.Count];

    manual.Set();

    for (int i = 0; i < availPorts.Count - 1; i++)
        {

        AutoResetEvent Auto = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        autos[i] = Auto;

        Thread t = new Thread(() => lookForValidDev(Auto, (object)availPorts[i]));
        t.Start();//start thread and pass it the port  

    }
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(autos);
    manual.Reset();

}


void lookForValidDev(AutoResetEvent auto, object obj)
{
    try
    {
         manual.WaitOne();
         // do something with obj 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        auto.Set();
    }


}
```

Comment: auto.Set() should be in a finally block

Answer (score 10):

The simplest and safest way to do this is to use a CountdownEvent. See [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_CountdownEvent).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that if the thread has terminated, the Join would return. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Store the Thread results in a list after they were spawned and iterate the list - during iteration call join then.  You still join linearly, but it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CountDownLatch:

```
public class CountDownLatch
{
    private int m_remain;
    private EventWaitHandle m_event;

    public CountDownLatch(int count)
    {
        Reset(count);
    }

    public void Reset(int count)
    {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        m_remain = count;
        m_event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        if (m_remain == 0)
        {
            m_event.Set();
        }
    }

    public void Signal()
    {
        // The last thread to signal also sets the event.
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_remain) == 0)
            m_event.Set();
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        m_event.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Example how to use it:

```
void StartThreads
{
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(availPorts.Count);

    foreach (cpsComms.cpsSerial ser in availPorts)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(lookForValidDev));

        //start thread and pass it the port and the latch
        t.Start((object)new Pair(ser, latch));

    }

    DoSomeWork();

    // wait for all the threads to signal
    latch.Wait();

    DoSomeMoreWork();
}

// In each thread
void NameOfRunMethod
{
    while(running)
    {
        // do work
    }

    // Signal that the thread is done running
    latch.Signal();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this included in .NET as CountdownEvent? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx