# Stop Execution utill all threads created in a for loop are terminated C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am saving some csv files using threads,
Threads are created in a loop
Here is the code

```
foreach (var f in Files)
{

   string tFile = f.ToString(); 
   Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>  SaveCSVFile(BulkExtractFolder, tFile));
   myThread.Start();
}

//save folder as zip file and download it
```

it starts saving csv files but when the zip file downloads it does not contain all files in it, because some threads are in execution when I zip this folder, How I can know that all threads started in for loop have completed their execution.

Comment: By not using threads, but tasks and ContinueWith. See [C# Waiting for multiple threads to finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281926/c-sharp-waiting-for-multiple-threads-to-finish), [Running multiple async tasks and waiting for them all to complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009437/running-multiple-async-tasks-and-waiting-for-them-all-to-complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are zipping/downloading the files in main thread then you can join all your child threads using `Thread.Join()` method. In which case, main thread will wait until all other threads have completed.

```
foreach (var f in Files)
{
   string tFile = f.ToString(); 
   Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>  SaveCSVFile(BulkExtractFolder, tFile));
   myThread.Start();
   myThread.Join();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to wait immediately after starting the thread you might as well just do all of the work in the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for `Parallel.ForEach`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Parallel.ForEach(Files, (f)=> {
   string tFile = f.ToString(); 
   SaveCSVFile(BulkExtractFolder, tFile);
});
```

And here is how you limit the number of threads: [How can I limit Parallel.ForEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290498/how-can-i-limit-parallel-foreach)

**Edit**: For older versions of .NET, this will work:

```
var numFiles = Files.Count; //or Files.Length, depending on what Files is
var threads = new Thread[numFiles];
for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(() =>  SaveCSVFile(BulkExtractFolder, Files[i]));
    threads[i].Start();
}
for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

Comment: The application I am working on is in MVC2 with Dot Net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4 or higher, you may use `Task` instead of `Thread` and `WaitAll` method.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var f in Files)
{
   string tFile = f.ToString(); 
   tasks.add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {               
             SaveCSVFile(BulkExtractFolder, tFile)
        });
   );
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.toArray());
```

Comment: The application I am working on is in MVC2 with Dot Net 3.5