# C#, I want the main thread output the "num" after all sub-thread end, how to do so? Now I can only get '0'

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
class Program
    {
        static void AddNumber1(ref int num)
        {
            num++;
        }
        static void AddNumber2(ref int num)
        {
            num++;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            int num = 0;

            var th1 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    AddNumber1(ref num);
                }
            });

            var th2 = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    AddNumber1(ref num);
                }
            });

            th1.Start();
            th2.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(num);

            Console.Write("Press any key to end :");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
```

Comment: `Thread.Join` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281926/c-sharp-waiting-for-multiple-threads-to-finish

Answer (score 0):

You also could use Tasks instead of Threads like

```
var th1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        AddNumber1(ref num);
    }
});

var th2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        AddNumber1(ref num);
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(th1, th2);

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Comment: also, Task.WhenAll(th1, th2)  could be used to return task which will be completed when all of the tasks are completed

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I solve the problem by your solution.

Comment: Well, I have a question. Will the two tasks use 'num' in a same time just like thread?

Comment: @suyangzuo they are running in parallel. Task is awrapper above Thread